# Need to match all word variations in this example

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

This will flag the words `betting`, `gambling`, `xxx` but it won't flag `Betting`, `Gambling`, `XXX`.

I'd like it to flag all variation of those words (i.e. Betting, BEttinG, BETTING, etc. etc.). Obviously, I can list them all separately, but I'd like to match them somehow so that all variations of those words would be flagged.

```
$original  = $_POST['message'];

$spamw = array('betting', 'gambling', 'xxx');

foreach ($spamw as $num) {
    if (( $pos = strpos( $original, $num )) !== false) { 
        $err = 'Something went wrong. Please, try again.';
    }
}
```

**SOLOVED**

```
$spamw = array('betting', 'gambling', 'xxx');
$original = $_POST['message'];

foreach ($spamw as $spamwords) {
  if (preg_match("/\b$spamwords\b/i", $original)) {
$err = 'Something went wrong. Please, try again.';
  }
}
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Comment: is it only the case differences you want to catch?  change `strpos` to `stripos`

Comment: @MrK ok. `i` *wink wink* still think you should ask for a case insensitive option on preg_match.

Comment: By the way my question is different (to whoever marked it as answered in another thread). In my case the *$_POST['message']* is submitted by users and may have all kinds of variations of those (and other spam words). I need to know what can be done in my existing example to match them, even though my array will have all spam words in lower case.

Comment: @Andreas how? I am not sure how.

Comment: U hv stored everything in lowercase..why don't you convert user's input to lower case and then compare? :P

Comment: ok how about `$original = strtolower($_POST['message']);`  that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to store all of the words that are in the `$spamw` array as lowercase, like you're doing now, and then use the PHP `strtolower()` function to convert any user-input to lowercase characters. Your PHP script could then compare the user-input to the values stored in the `$spamw` array, checking to see if any of the words happen to match.

Comment: You mean like: $original  = strtolower('$_POST[message]');

Comment: Thanks @Jamiemcg $original = strtolower($_POST['message']); was what I needed.

Comment: Yes, something like that might work for what you're looking to accomplish. You could even create another variable, if you'd like, to store the text that is converted to lowercase, if it helps to keep things organized.

Answer (score 0):

ok i update the sollution with 0.1 % of all variations i have in my mind:

```
<?php
function tospam($dictswrd){
    global $word;
    print('the imput is <span style="color:red">'.$word.'</span> compare to <span style="color:blue">'.$dictswrd.'</span> from Dictionary<br>');
    $pattern = '/(?<!\p{L})'.strtolower($word).'*/iu';
    return preg_match($pattern,$dictswrd ) >0;
}




$dictionary = array('betting', 'gambling', 'xxx'); //a small internal database loaded from a internal file maybe file?
/*
 eg:
$dictionary =file('spam_dictionary.txt');
internal you can drop a file 
spam_dictionary.txt :
---------------
betting
gambling
xxx
---------------
or you can fill the array of dictionary from a kind of database=any kind
*/

if(isset($_POST['message'])){
    print('<h1>FORM`s POST method 1</h1>');

    $word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
    $result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
    print_r($result_spam_or_not);print('<hr>');

    $word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
    $result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
    print_r($result_spam_or_not);print('<hr>');


    $word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
    $result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
    print_r($result_spam_or_not);print('<hr>');

//or
print('<h1>FORM`s POST method 2</h1>');

$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print(!empty($result_spam_or_not)? 'SPAM':'ok!');print('<hr>');



$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print(!empty($result_spam_or_not)? 'SPAM':'ok!');print('<hr>');


$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print(!empty($result_spam_or_not)? 'SPAM':'ok!');print('<hr>');


//or
print('<h1>FORM`s POST method 3</h1>');

$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
if(!empty($result_spam_or_not))print('spam');else print('not a spam');print('<hr>');



$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
if(!empty($result_spam_or_not))print('spam');else print('not a spam');print('<hr>');


$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
if(!empty($result_spam_or_not))print('spam');else print('not a spam');print('<hr>');

}


print('<h1>method 1</h1>');

$word='Gambling';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print_r($result_spam_or_not);print('<hr>');

$word='gambling';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print_r($result_spam_or_not);print('<hr>');


$word='blablabla';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print_r($result_spam_or_not);print('<hr>');


//or
print('<h1>method 2</h1>');

$word='Gambling';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print(!empty($result_spam_or_not)? 'SPAM':'ok!');print('<hr>');



$word='gambling';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print(!empty($result_spam_or_not)? 'SPAM':'ok!');print('<hr>');


$word='blablabla';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
print(!empty($result_spam_or_not)? 'SPAM':'ok!');print('<hr>');


//or
print('<h1>method 3</h1>');

$word='Gambling';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
if(!empty($result_spam_or_not))print('spam');else print('not a spam');print('<hr>');



$word='gambling';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
if(!empty($result_spam_or_not))print('spam');else print('not a spam');print('<hr>');


$word='blablabla';//$word=$_POST['message'];//let's say that's coming from input from post
$result_spam_or_not=array_filter($dictionary,'tospam' );
if(!empty($result_spam_or_not))print('spam');else print('not a spam');print('<hr>');


?><form method="post" action="">
    spam!<input type="text" name="message" value="Gambling"><input type="submit">
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    spam!<input type="text" name="message" value="gambling"><input type="submit">
</form>
<form method="post" action="">
    not a spam!<input type="text" name="message" value="blablabla"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure how that helps to my original question.

Comment: i'll be back with preg_match example

Comment: i did the update.i posting this in case you cannot receive i modify the sollution

Comment: The easiest solution was this: 

    $spamw = array('betting', 'gambling', 'xxx');
    $original = $_POST['message'];

    foreach ($spamw as $spamwords) {
      if (preg_match("/\b$spamwords\b/i", $original)) {
    $err = 'Something went wrong. Please, try again.';
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [stripos](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) function, which finds the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring, instead of `strpos`.